# Is Topological Space an Algebraic Structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

Is a Topological Space an Algebraic Structure?

I am referring to the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure):

> algebraic structure generally refers to a set (called carrier set or underlying set) with one or more finitary operations defined on it that satisfies a list of axioms. Examples of algebraic structures include groups, rings, fields, and lattices. More complex structures can be defined by introducing multiple operations, different underlying sets, or by altering the defining axioms. Examples of more complex algebraic structures include vector spaces, modules, and algebras.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by that.

Comment: Does the definition of a Topological Space imply that it is an Algebriac Structure in the sense of Abstract Algebra ?

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. Can you give a precise definition of "algebraic structure"? Without a definition there can be no answer.

Comment: It is not clear enough to be answered.

Comment: @ZhenLin I know there  is an interpretation of compact Hausdorf spaces as algebras over a certain monad in the category of sets. May be there is a similar fact about topological spaces.

Comment: to Zhen Lin "algebraic structure generally refers to a set (called carrier set or underlying set) with one or more finitary operations defined on it that satisfies a list of axioms.
Examples of algebraic structures include groups, rings, fields, and lattices. More complex structures can be defined by introducing multiple operations, different underlying sets, or by altering the defining axioms. Examples of more complex algebraic structures include vector spaces, modules, and algebras." Wikipedia

Answer (score 2):

If you require finitary operations, then no, the category of topological spaces is not algebraic in that sense. But if you allow infinitary operation, then (famously) the category of topological spaces is the category of algebras for a suitable filter monad, and in that sense is algebraic.

Comment: That's interesting... There seems to be no end to the alchemy of category theory.

Comment: It is a beautiful result. I'm not sure it's alchemy. Basically, a Hausdorff compact topological space is algebraic in the sense that to any ultrafilter in it (which must converge to a unique point), there is associated a point in the space (the limit!). This is very much like an infinitary algebraic operation. Getting rid of the compact just requires some careful tinkering with the ultrafilter monad.

Comment: $\mathbf{Top}$ cannot be monadic over $\mathbf{Set}$, because it is not a regular category. Perhaps you are thinking of the infamous "relational $\beta$-modules" – but it would be a big stretch to call that an algebraic structure.

Comment: Ahh, that's a simple way of thinking about it. I am having a lot of trouble getting good search this, but I am probably not using the right terms. I don't know anything about monads.

Comment: @ZhenLin why is that a big stretch?

Comment: I think it is entirely reasonable to demand that the result of an algebraic operation is well defined – at minimum, unique if it exists. Multi-valued  operations can hardly be said to be algebraic.

Comment: @ZhenLin wouldn't you consider, say, monoid objects in Rel with respect to the tensor product given by the cartesian product of sets to be algebraic structures? I don't see why multivaluedness means non-algebraic.

Comment: @rschwieb [A monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors, what's the problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870088/a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-problem) <- We have a question for everything on the network ;-)

Comment: By my definition, they are not algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially everything called an "algebraic structure" is a set (or more than one set) with operations that combine elements.

In a topological space, you get a set and a special family of subsets of the space. There is nothing here about combining elements. So no, there is no general connection.

There are many examples of topological algebraic structures, though.

Comment: Do you mean that "abstract" topology in general not related to any algebraic structure, but one may generate more topological algebraic structures!

Comment: @maryam I mean that the definition of a topology does not provide an algebraic structure (that I know of). If this is what you are saying, then I agree.

Comment: there is what's called the "Neighbourhoods definition" of Topological Space in Wikipedia. It has the flavor of the definition of Normed Space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space

Comment: @HaiderAtrah I'm not sure what you are saying. A normed vector space (if that's what you're referring to) is *a fortiori* a vector space, and that is of course an algebraic structure. But that has nothing to do with the topology. As I mentioned, there are lots of algebraic objects with topologies...

Comment: Wait, topologies are magmas under the intersection operation though so they define a structure naturally in at least in that sense, right?

Comment: @PineappleFish sure, the open sets are even a ring of sets, but at that point you’ve ceased talking about a set and its topology and started talking about a different set with binary operations. It’s not topology anymore.

Answer (score 1):

"*The* definition of topological space"? There are a few equivalent ones. The most common one -- "a topological space is a set X together with a collection $\mathscr{T}$ of subsets of X closed under $\cap$, $\bigcup$, and containing $\emptyset$ and X" is clearly not algebraic in the standard sense of 'algebraic structure' – $\bigcup$ is not a finitary operation.

However, perhaps [*or perhaps not – I'm guessing*] you have in mind the axioms for the closure operator (or the interior operator), by means of which one can characterize the closed sets, hence the open sets, hence a topology. The closure operator axioms aren't completely algebraic: one of them requires that $A \subseteq cl(A)$ for any $A \subseteq X$.

Generalization requires at least a join operation, and a notion of partial ordering, possibly defined in terms of the join operation as is done with lattices and Boolean algebras ($x \le y \iff x \vee y = y$). So perhaps these notions can be pinned down by considering structures $(L, \wedge, \vee, 0, 1, cl)$ where:

- $(L, \wedge, \vee, 0, 1)$ is a lattice, with top and bottom elements $1$ and $0$ respectively, and
- $cl \colon L \to L$ satisfies these axioms, for $a, b \in L$:

  1. $cl(0) = 0$
  2. $cl(a \vee b) = cl(a) \vee cl(b)$
  3. $a \vee cl(a) = cl(a)$
  4. $cl(cl(a)) = cl(a)$

Considering Boolean algebras rather than just lattices – adding a complement operator with standard behavior – would get closer to topology than the above definition. But none of Kuratowski's closure axioms, which 1. - 4. above adapt, mention set complements.

Comment: So am I correct in that $\sigma$-algebra is not an algebraic structure since it is not only involved with finitary operations?

Comment: @cliu55 A $\sigma$-algebra actually *is* an algebraic structure in the generalized sense of *universal algebra*: the operation of countable union has a definite signature $B^{\omega} \rightarrow B$, whereas that's not true of the union operator defined on arbitrary subsets of $B$.