# Is a homeomorphism a homomorphism?

Tags: morphism

Wikipedia states that homomorphisms are structure preserving maps from one **algebraic** structure to another.

A homeomorphism is a topology-preserving map from one topological space to another (that also admits an inverse).

However, since a topological space is a mathematical structure but **not** an **algebraic** structure, that would mean that a homeomorphism is not a homomorphism (though it is an isomorphism).

Is that true, or should I ignore wikipedia and assume that the term homomorphism can also apply to maps on non-algbraic structures?

Comment: Topological spaces are algebraic structures in the sense of category theory.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477942/is-topological-space-an-algebraic-structure

Comment: The "structure" a homeomorphism preserves is the topology.